# How to use Razor View Engine in a console application?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

My console app needs to send HTML emails. I'd like to write the emails in HTML format in a Razor view and have the engine generate the email body content.

This means no controllers or requests. How could I go about this?

Comment: I wonder what would be the answer to this question after 6 years? Now, I have a requirement to parse the HTML template and replace the values using @Model.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an open source project which allows to use Razor as a general templating engine: it's called [RazorEngine](http://razorengine.codeplex.com/) (the code in on [GitHub](https://github.com/Antaris/RazorEngine))

A sample for the project's page:

```
string template = "Hello @Model.Name! Welcome to Razor!";
string result = Razor.Parse(template, new { Name = "World" });
```

Comment: Yes I've seen it but I like the idea of having views in separate files.

Comment: You can put your templates in separate files, just load the template from the file and pass it to the engine.

Comment: I've downloaded it and messed around before, looks promising.

Comment: I used this but not a huge fan, although I'm not aware of a better alternative. My biggest issue is that I can't get it to support strongly typed models.

Comment: I'm using it and it's quite good. But it has following drawbacks: 1- no strongly type model. 2- you cannot use html helper. So, no partial view then :S!3- if you use version 3.0 it supports layout and section but it is super slow and will kill your machine!!

Comment: Just a quick note that it does support strongly typed models. I think it has improved a lot since 2012.

Answer (score 6):

I have a [demo project on GitHub](https://github.com/danmalcolm/NonHttpRunTimeRazorSupport) that demonstrates how to use Razor views to render content outside of the context of a running ASP.Net application. It provides full support for layouts, _ViewStart files, partials, HtmlHelper, Urlhelper etc.

Note that it uses the [RazorGenerator](http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/) Visual Studio tool to precompile Razor templates.

See my introductory [blog post](http://www.danmalcolm.com/2013/10/razor-views-outside-of-web-application.html) for further background.

Comment: Looks promising. Nuget support would ineed be nice :)