# How to create RazorEngineHost for RazorTemplateEngin in non MVC project

Tags: c#, .net, razor, razorengine

I'm using `RazorEngine` in an Console application.

I want to initialise `RazorEngineHost` and pass into `RazorTemplateEngin`. However as I can see in MSDN documentations it says `RazorEngineHost` "is not intended to be used directly from your code".[RazorEngineHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.razorenginehost(v=vs.111).aspx)

So what is the best way of creating `RazorTemplateEngin`?

This question quite different from [How to use Razor View Engine in a console application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9426019/how-to-use-razor-view-engine-in-a-console-application)> I want to use RazorTemplateEngin becuse I have template not string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a look at [RazorTemplateEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.razor.razortemplateengine(v=vs.111).aspx) on MSDN you can see that the documentation for that also says "not intended to be used directly from your code", that doesn't mean that you can't. If you want to use an instance of `RazorTemplateEngine`you have to pass in a `RazorEngineHost` instance. Have a look at this blog post for usage: [Leveraging Razor Templates Outside of ASP.NET](http://www.codemag.com/article/1103081)

```
var language = new CSharpRazorCodeLanguage();
var host = new RazorEngineHost(language) {
   DefaultBaseClass = "OrderInfoTemplateBase",
   DefaultClassName = "OrderInfoTemplate",
   DefaultNamespace = "CompiledRazorTemplates",
};

host.NamespaceImports.Add("System");
```

> To begin, the RazorEngineHost’s constructor accepts a RazorCodeLanguage specifying the target template’s code language. This example produces a host that can parse Razor templates written using C#. To support templates written in Visual Basic, supply a VBRazorCodeLanguage instance instead. The additional initializer properties instruct the code generator to emit code with a particular class name, deriving from a custom template base class, and residing in a particular namespace. Finally, add the System namespace to the list of imported namespaces required for the generated class to compile just as you would import a namespace in a normal, hand-written class.